# Highchart series data value Double array

Tags: arrays, highcharts, series

I am making a high chart stock chart.
The data is specified in the array below.

```
[[1542205800000,46.7] [1542292200000,47.85] [1542378600000,48.38] ...]
```

I get an error when generating the graph.
I am getting the following error:
Highcharts error #18

Seek advice.

```
function funChartDraw(strMenuTopSeq, strMenuSubSeq, result){
            
            var dataList    = [];
            var dataRow     = [];
            
            for(var i = 0; i < result[0].chartValue.length; i++){
                dataRow = result[0].chartValue[i];
                dataList.push([
                    Number(dataRow[0]),
                    Number(dataRow[1])
                ])
            }
            
            console.log("dataList : ", dataList);
            
            Highcharts.stockChart('dataChart', {

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
                },

                series: [{
                            name: 'AAPL',
                            data: dataList,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2
                            }
                        }]
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with the sample of your data? You can start from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9hznsey/

Comment: thank. I did it your way